# What is the SECRET parameter in Symfony2 used for?

Tags: symfony, yaml

can anyone tell me what is the SECRET parameter of parameters.yml in Symfony2?

Comment: No one knows. If someone knew it would not be secret any more.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is a **security-related** parameter used by the framework. From the doc :

> This is a string that should be unique to your application and it's commonly used to add more entropy to security related operations. Its value should be a series of characters, numbers and symbols chosen randomly and the recommended length is around 32 characters.

Symfony2 uses this secret parameter for example to generate **csrf tokens**.

You can find more details, examples in the doc regarding the [secret parameter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#secret).

Comment: The linked site is a poor password generator. Symfony recommends including letters, number and symbols and there's no reason to limit the letters to [a-f].

Comment: Yes better use http://www.freepasswordgenerator.com or one of the million webs for password generation and get sure to check all possible characters (numbers, lowercase, uppercase and symbols).

Comment: My comment is a bit wrong, if you use symbols have in mind that for example the symbol `%` have the meaning of a parameter so better **don't use symbols** if you want to be sure it's ok.

Answer (score 11):

You just need to open console (on unix/mac/bsd) and run this command to get some random number with lenght 48:

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install pwgen
$ pwgen 48 1 -By
```

which will produces something like this:

`` bah7oTeixi~to.aFoh~quoh~Yee3eequomae7aib`ie#hoo7 ``

or you just could use your dev/urandom for that:

`$ cat /dev/urandom | strings --bytes 1 | tr -d '\n\t [](){}"' | head --bytes 48`

after that you could set it as value of secret parameter instead of **ThisTokenIsNotSecretChangeIt**

I also do not recommend to use http://nux.net/secret for that because of limited length and limited secret number's alphabet (a-f0-9+)